# iimage-mode - resize an image in Markdown mode to fit the window

Tags: images, image-mode

I would love to be able to see images in Markdown that are rescaled to fit into my window. I googled for the answer but could not find how to rescale images shown with iimage-mode in Markdown. I can see a solution for org-mode or an image open with Emacs. Any idea how to do this to an inline-image in Markdown?

Workaround for now: `for i in *; do convert $i -resize 800x500\> ../imgs/$i; done` I rescale images in the terminal and then use them in my notes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Resizing images only works for images types supported by the imagemagick-library.
The function `imagemagick-types` returns a list of these types.

**EDIT:** Input <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq val (imagemagick-types))` <kbd>RET</kbd> and <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `val` <kbd>RET</kbd> to check what the function returns.
If the value of `val` is `nil` imagemagick is not enabled and you are out of luck. If the value is a list look whether your image type is member of that list.

For enabling all types supported by imagemagick set `imagemagick-enabled-types` to `t`.
You can do that with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `imagemagick-enabled-types` <kbd>RET</kbd>. Just use the option *Support all ImageMagick types* from the *Value* menu.

If this prerequisites are fulfilled you can use the following lisp code to adapt
the image width to the window width in markdown-buffers.

```el
(setq imagemagick-enabled-types t) 

(defun image-p (obj)
  "Return non-nil if OBJ is an image"
  (eq (car-safe obj) 'image))


(defun iimage-scale-to-fit-width ()
  "Scale over-sized images in the active buffer to the width of the currently selected window.
  (imagemagick must be enabled)"
  (interactive)
  (let ((max-width (window-width (selected-window) t)))
    (alter-text-property (point-min) (point-max)
                         'display
                         (lambda (prop)
                           (when (image-p prop)
                             (plist-put (cdr prop) :type 'imagemagick)
                             (plist-put (cdr prop) :max-width max-width)
                             prop)))))

(defun iimage-scale-on-window-configuration-change ()
  "Hook function for major mode that display inline images:
Adapt image size via `iimage-scale-to-fit-width' when the window size changes."
  (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook #'iimage-scale-to-fit-width t t))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook #'iimage-scale-on-window-configuration-change)
```

Comment: Thanks, Tobias. I tried to use this but I can not get it to run. I see iimage-scale-to-fit-width function when I M-x iimage-<tab>, so it seems that it's loaded properly. However, when I switch on the iimage mode, M-x iimage-mode nothing changes (I don't get any images inserted). I don't now lisp thus I don't know what kind of information would help you to understand the problem.

Comment: @MarcinMagnus I added instructions how to test the return value of `imagemagick-types` and how to switch on the support of all types.

Answer (score 1):

The newest [markdown-mode](https://github.com/defunkt/markdown-mode) introduced markdown-max-image-size for resizing large images. It does the job! Emacs has to be compiled with ImageMagick support (`--with-imagemagick`).

Comment: legend! Works on my windows machine for crying out loud! `C-h v markdown-max-image-size` --> `customize` --> Change `Maximum width in pixels`, NO NEED RESTART OR ANYTHING, JUST TOGGLE THE IMAGES AND IT WORKS. :) I am using `GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)  of 2020-08-21` with windows 10.

Comment: P.S. I **did not do** any special compile with ImageMagick support.